# Integral, partial fractions, need explanation for how to get from one step to another.

Tags: calculus, integration

[image]

Can someone explain how they go from the red step to the blue one?

Comment: 5x = 5x + 20 - 20

Comment: Why was 20 chosen?

Comment: Good question. The answer lies in observing the derivative of the denominator, which is $2x + 8 = 2(x+4)$ Now the question is, how can we write the numerator as the derivative of the denominator ? We want to do this because the integral of this is the log function.

Comment: Ok yea that makes sense. Thanks a lot.

Comment: So, now we have, 2(x + 4). The coefficient of x is already five and we want to make it 2. So we multiply and divide by 5/2 and we get 5/2*(2x). Now we want to bring in eight. But, we can't just bring in eight like that because the x is multiplied by something. So we add and subtract, 5/2*(8) which gives us 20.

Comment: What we do now is write it as 5/2*(2x + 8) or as simply 5x + 20. 2x + 8 is the the derivative of the denominator so we add and subtract 20. The other fraction with -20 is easy to evaluate because all you have to do is complete the square in the denominator and we get the derivative of the inverse tangent function !

Comment: Adding and subtracting the same quantity to manipulate functions into derivatives or integrals of known functions, is a common trick in calculus. I hope I gave you seem insight.

Comment: Yea, you did. Thanks a lot. I really appreciate the in depth explanation. My pre calculus math background isn't so great, and while I was fine in calc. 1, going into calc 2 I keep running into sooo much I guess I should have known before hand. But thanks to people like you here in this site it hasn't yet turned into the complete disaster it could be.

Comment: No problem. Now that you have had a discussion about this problem, you should be able to apply this the next time you encounter this. If you see a function of x in the numerator, and a function of x in the denominator who's degree is greater than the numerator, always suspect how you can write the numerator as the derivative of the denominator. This pleasantly evaluates to the logarithm function. I find it very elegant that a function that looks very tough changes completely on changing the variable !

Comment: And when there is just a number, try to write the denominator by completing the square and this works out to be the inverse tangent. Let me know if you need any more help for future problems.

Comment: And, there's one more thing I'd like yo tell you about these kind of problems. What do you do when the numerator has a degree greater than the denominator? It's simple. You perform division. So if N(x) is the numerator and D(x) is the denominator, you write N(x) = Q(x)D(x) + R(x) where R(x) is the remainder and naturally has a degree less than the denominator. In the other term, the denominator gets cancelled and we're left to evaluate the integral of Q(x)... A strsightforward polynomial that is not a fraction!

Comment: Thanks again for all the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, the red part isn't equal to the blue one, but you should note that the sum in the blue part continues on the next line, and that $5x+20-20=5x$ to see how the first part was changed. It's almost the same for the other fraction.

Comment: Ohhhh ok. I see it now. Looking at it all wrong. Thanks.

Comment: .....Why the number 20?

Comment: In order to be able to write the variable change used to evaluate $I_1$ more conveniently: with $u=x^2+8x+17$, we have $du=2(x+4)dx$, and $5x+20=5(x+4)$